# Using Json format in Confluent Platform Schema Registry?

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to put several event types in the same Kafka topic using the JSON format, but in the Producer implementation I'm always getting `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing JSON message`. Seems that the annotation @Schema isn't working as expected is like the schema defined by the annotation isn't enriched properly and in the method that validates the [backward compatibility](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/d5286ae2817c2c137912e6afbb8232c878d87685/json-schema-provider/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/json/JsonSchema.java#L308) the schema defined by my event has the schemaObj empty and the result is not compatible and fails.

My event:

```
@Schema(
  value = "1",
  refs = Array(new SchemaReference(name = "event", subject = "event"))
)
case class Event(@BeanProperty id: String,
                  @BeanProperty name: String)
```

Producer:

```
def send(): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties() {
      put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
      put(
        ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
      )
      put(
        ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer"
      )
      put("auto.register.schemas", "false")
      put("use.latest.version", "true")
      put("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081")
      put("json.fail.invalid.schema", "true") 
    }

    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, Event](props)

    val topic = "all-json"
    val key = "key1"
    val event = Event("id", "name")

    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, Event](topic, key, event)
    producer.send(record).get
}
```

By the command line, I can perfectly produce the events. The JSON Schema is modeled by

```
{
  "oneOf": [
     { "$ref": "Event.schema.json" },
     { "$ref": "EventB.schema.json" }
  ]
}

...
```

the dependencies of confluent used are the version 6.0.1.

Do you know what is the issue?